# Can't run VSCode as superuser

Tags: permissions, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run VSCode as a superuser in Ubuntu 18.04, It's solely in a lab environment to allow me to work with Ansible. Every time I load VSCode as superuser I get a white screen and nothing else, but when loaded via the "code" it works fine.

[image]

I could really do with it loading with superuser privileges to allow me to do my Ansible labs.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, rolling back to version 1.65 seems to be the only viable solution.

The reason for the problem is an update: running VSCode as "sudo" was broken in newer releases, and the VSCode developers closed this issue as "wontfix": https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146445

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try running without `--user-data-dir` argument because maybe you have some misconfiguration there.

I had a similar problem but with gray screen some time ago and I've just deleted `.vscode` folder

Comment: Hi Ivan, Thanks for taking the time to message back but unfortunately sudo code --no-sandbox =/root/ didn't work

Comment: @simonclarke Have you tried to reinstall Code?

Comment: Yes Ivan tried that but unfortunately that didn't work either

Comment: @simonclarke I recommend running `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` because maybe your problem is caused by old underlying software

Comment: Thanks again Ivan for taking the time to reply. I have tried that and it didn't work unfortunately still getting the white screen

Comment: @simonclarke I think you should update your system. You can do this by running `sudo do-release-upgrade`